# Text appearing between images

Tags: floats

I have a few images in my latex document. But some portion of text comes right after a subsection of images. I want my text to come after all my images. I've looked at other answers where they suggest using `\newpage` or `\clearpage` but that is not what I am looking for. For instance, here is a screenshot of how it looks like right now -

[image]

I want the text highlighted in red to come after all the images. How do I do that? The LaTeX code is shown below -

```
\subsection{Confusion Matrices}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Uniflow Decision Tree]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{uni_decisiontree.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Uniflow KNN]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{uni_knn.png} }}%
    
    
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Uniflow Linear]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{uni_linear.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Uniflow Naive]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{uni_naive.png} }}%
    
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Uniflow Perceptron]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{uni_pcp.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Uniflow Random Forest]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{uni_random_forest.png} }}%
    
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Biflow Decision Tree]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{bi_decision_tree.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Biflow KNN]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{bi_KNN.png} }}%
    
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Biflow Linear]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{bi_linear.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Biflow Naive]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{bi_naive.png} }}%
    
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Biflow Perceptron]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{bi_pcp.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Biflow Random Forest]{{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{bi_random_forest.png} }}%
    
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}



Finally, we use various metrics to evaluate the performance of different machine learning models. The different metrics that we use are - 
\[ Precision = TP /(TP + FP) \]
\[    Recall = TP /(TP + FN) \]
\[  F1-Score = (2*TP) /(2*TP + FP + FN) \]
\[  Accuracy = (TP + TN) /(P + N) \] \paragraph{}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please complete your given code to be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: you are forcing the figures to float a long way by using `[h!]` which means not top, not bottom and not on  a float page, which does not leave many options. You probably get a warning and it gets changed to `[ht]`